# Loading a .tif.ovr file on QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I am quite new to QGIS so I hope the question will be clear enough. I downloaded a TIFF folder that contains the following file formats:

1. .ovr
2. .tif.ovr
3. .tif.ovr.aux.xml
4. .tif.xml

As far as I understood, I will need to load the .tif.ovr file into QGIS (raster + image pyramids) but this doesn't seem to be supported. I'm not sure if it's a licensing issue since I downloaded the data from ArcGIS. If so, is there a way around this?

Comment: Does the folder contain a file with just the `.tif` extension?

Answer (score 5):

The `.ovr` files are overviews of the tif file and QGis will make use of them when it needs to. So there is no need to add them separately, just add the `.tif` file and QGis will find the other files provided they are in the same directory.